# Equivalent of int[] a = new int[500]; in Java in Swift?

Tags: java, ios, swift

In Java, I can do this: `int[] a = new int[500];`. However in Swift, there seemed like there's no way I can create such a fixed size array without initializing all the variables in the array(which is quite impossible for an array of 500 elements). My goal here is to create a array of 160 SKSpriteNode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395105/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-array-of-objects

Comment: In Java, those 500 elements are `0`. It's an array of primitives.

Comment: Swift’s Array type also provides an initializer for creating an array of a certain size with all of its values set to a provided default value. You pass this initializer the number of items to be added to the new array (called count) and a default value of the appropriate type (called repeatedValue)

Comment: For primitive array, try this... var myArray : [Int] =  [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)