# Why it's wrong to init array in this way in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

I'm going to init an array with 6 UIImageViews in this way:

```
var imageViews = [UIImageView](repeating: UIImageView(), count: 6)
```

But I found that every element in it has the same address. If I change one imageView I'll change all of them.

I don't know how it works and what should I do to separate them?

Comment: There are a few ideas posted in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395105/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how it works.

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init), it states:

> Creates a new collection containing the specified number of a **single**, repeated value.

If you want separate values, create them explicity

```
var imageViews = [UIImageView(), UIImageView(), UIImageView(), ...]
```

Or use a loop. But always check the docs if something unexpected happens because you will either have found a bug in the SDK, or an error in your own assumptions.