# How to create fixed-size 2d array in swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

Recently I am doing some code tests and found that fixed-size array creation is not as simple in Swift compare to other languages, say c++.

I have seen the solution for 1d array here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395105/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-array-of-objects#24395552):

One Dimension array, compare c++ with Swift:

```
// In c++

int array1[64];    // 1-dimension array size 64

// In Swift

var array1 = [Int?](repeating: nil, count: 64) // 1 dimension array size 64
```

For 2-dimension array:

```
// in c++

int array2[64][64]; // 2-dimension array size 64x64

// in Swift

var array2 : [[Int?]] = ???????
```

How to initiate a fixed-size 2d array in swift?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by testing it out in Playground, here's the solution:

In c++

```
int array1[64];    // 1-dimension array size 64

int array2[64][64]; // 2-dimension array size 64x64
```

in Swift:

```
var array1 = [Int?](repeating: nil, count: 64) // 1 dimension array

var array2 = [[Int?]](
 repeating: [Int?](repeating: nil, count: 64)
 count: 64
) // 2-dimension array size 64x64

// Access it like normal

array2[4][2] = 42
print(array2[4][2]) // output: 42
```

A bonus, 3-dimension array in swift !!!

```
var array3 = 
[[[Int?]]](
  repeating: [[Int?]](
    repeating: [Int?](
      repeating: nil,
      count: 3),
  count: 3),
count: 3)
```

Comment: In what sense is this "fixed size"? And what's `var` in the 5th line?

Comment: declaring the size of the array without any value in it

Comment: just noticed the error of the `var` and corrected it

Comment: Okay but just so you know it is not “fixed”. The size can change.

Comment: you are right, i think it is more like a pre-declared and initiated with a given size? what is a better terminology?